# VSC Live Server is driving me nuts

Tags: visual-studio, liveserver

I don't get how this thing is so buggy on my mac ugh

Firstly it is such a hassle to open cuz it won't open in chrome without typing in the IP manually (is there still no solution besides changing settings that won't work)??

But most importantly, my CSS file is just not loading...
I did everything already from restart to reinstall, etc.
And when I open the file from Chrome the code does works so it's not my link...

Does anyone have another solution for the CSS to load, please?

Answer (score 0):

To give some feedback (after a LOT of crying and tinkering around)...

I think fixed the CSS file not loading on Live Server? It seems that the extension loads the resources as if the folder the HTML is in is the root, so I had to use a relative path (which took a WHILE to get to its liking as well...)
Still not opening without a fuss though haha...